# How to add custom filter in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I need to add the filter to handle pagination in an existing app,

In index.js we have all the

`require('angular')
require('angular-ui-notification');`

```
var myapp= angular.module('myapp', [
'ngRoute',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ngSanitize',
'ui.bootstrap'
]);
$http.get('configuration.json').then(function (response) {
var parameters = {};
parameters = response.data;
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    mainModule
        .controller('SimpleCtrl', require('./controllers/Simple.js'))       
        .provider('runtimeConfig', require('./services/configuration.js'))          
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
                        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
        })
        .config(function(runtimeConfigProvider){             
        })            
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    template: require('../views/myHome.html'),
                    controller: require('./controllers/myHome.js'),
        accessPolicy: { authentication: false, role: "ALL"}
                })              
        })
        })
        })
```

For corresponding myHome.html, I need to add the pagination where I have myHome.js file ,

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function($scope, $filter, $log, $route, $rootScope, $location, uibModal, MyService) {

}
```

where I am planning to use the below  code.

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}

//We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
//let's make a startFrom filter
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= data.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>
</div>
```

But I don't know how to inject particular filter code in myHome.js,

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
}
});
```

where I have my app in index.js and need to do pagination from myHome.js. Please suggest how to use the code to myHome.js. I am getting the below exception if I try to use startFrom,

```
bundle.annotated.js:29401 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 
startFromFilterProvider <- startFromFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=startFromFilterProvider%20%3C-<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">tartFromFilter
    at http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:16992:12
    at http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:21213:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:21361:39)
    at http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:21218:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:21361:39)
    at http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:35153:24
    at new module.exports (http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:550:18)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:21402:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:21410:27)
    at http://localhost:9000/bundle.annotated.js:26075:28
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of filters to add as dependency in controller is,

`filterName+Filter`

`Eg: testFilter, reverseFilter, startFromFilter`

As per our discussion offline, your filter can go to,

```
mainModule 
.filter('startFrom', function() { 
return function(input, start) { 
start = +start; //parse to int 
return input.slice(start); 
} 
})
```

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$filter', function ($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.q = '';
    
    $scope.getData = function () {
      // needed for the pagination calc
      // https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter
      return $filter('filter')($scope.data, $scope.q)

    }
    
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.getData().length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    
    for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }
}]);

//We already have a limitTo filter built-in to angular,
//let's make a startFrom filter
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="q" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter text">
    <select ng-model="pageSize" id="pageSize" class="form-control">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
     </select>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:q | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
            {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1">
        Previous
    </button>
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= getData().length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1">
        Next
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I have tried but again I am getting the same exception. I have copied the function to myHome.js but the exception is coming.  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: startFromFilterFilterProvider <- startFromFilterFilter

Comment: have you added the file which contain the filter to index.html file

Comment: I have added like this, 
'use strict';
module.exports = function($scope, $filter, $log, $route, $rootScope, $location, uibModal, MyService) {

 var startFrom = $filter('startFrom');

function MyCtrl($scope,startFromFilter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.pageSize = 10;
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
        return Math.ceil($scope.data.length/$scope.pageSize);                
    }
    for (var i=0; i<45; i++) {
        $scope.data.push("Item "+i);
    }

   $scope.filtered = startFromFilter(data); // you can use something like this
}
}

Comment: `function($scope, $filter, $log, $route, $rootScope, $location, uibModal, MyService,startFromFilter)`

Comment: I am getting this exception after adding ,
bundle.annotated.js:29405 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: startFromFilterProvider <- startFromFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=startFromFilterProvider%20%3C-<div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">tartFromFilter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126226/discussion-between-user3428736-and-sravan).

Comment: It works instead of hardcoded option values,  need to do with the existing page values exists!! Thanks..

Comment: On selecting the option say 5,10 my page number is not updating 
For example total data is 13 for pagesize=5 it will display in 3 pages but in case of pagesize=10 the currentPAge/totalPage should be 1/2 but it is displaying 1/3